# How to increase the length of a TextField while pressing "Enter" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a textfield of maxLength set to 150. However, I want to textField's maxLine property to increase by 1 as I press enter. How can I achieve this please?

Find my code below:

```
child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        maxLines: 5,
                        maxLength: 150,
                        controller: _userAboutController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          helperText: '(Optional)',
                          labelText: user.about,
                          icon: Image.asset(
                            "Assets/images/country.png",
                            height: 40.0,
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: secondaryColor, width: 2.0),
                          ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare  `int maxLines = 5`
2. When enter pressed, add increment for `maxLines`.

   `maxLines ++`;
3. Finally change textField

   `maxLines: 5` to `maxLines ;`